# Xcode 10 Alamofire Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

Failing to build an Xcode project for the first time with Alamofire and SwiftyJSON. Getting the error:

```
Code Signing /Users/tc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Theo's_App-dettsmkxqclxnkgyvtofbjnhseyp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Theo's App.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity -
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign -  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/tc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Theo's_App-dettsmkxqclxnkgyvtofbjnhseyp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Theo's App.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/tc/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Theos_App-dettsmkxqclxnkgyvtofbjnhseyp/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Theos App.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: No such file or directory
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Tried finding similar issues online and doing their solutions but build keeps failing.

Comment: I know this might be a silly question but still I gotta ask to be sure. Did you try clean and build?

Comment: Sometimes I canceled progress building, the error appear. Try clean and build agian.

Comment: i tried two three times, still its showing the same issue.!

Answer (score 2):

@Cœur, I was facing the same issue with Xcode 10 recently. Not sure if it will work for you.

Try to close Xcode, and open your project xxx.xcworkspace from the **finder** instead of the xcode recent project panel.

Seems like there's a bug in Xcode 10.